# How can I talk to Odahviing again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have trapped Odahviing in Dragonsreach, and it seems that I must free him so that I can ride him to the next dungeon.

The problem is, every time I free him, everyone else in the room starts attacking him. Since the Jarl (who is invincible) is in the room, and the dragon itself is invincible, this enters a neverending cycle of one of the two of them dying, crouching for a moment to recover, and resuming battle. I can't talk to Odahviing while he is fighting.

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Doesn't the Jarl eventually go outside or out of reach? That might be an option...

Comment: @TomWijsman I've tried waiting, but he seems intent on standing in the corner staring the dragon down.

Comment: Can you somehow change the situation by using the wait system for some hours? I can't try this for myself because he got killed in my case, if I think I have the right person in mind...

Comment: I have the same exact problem! but I'm going to try the waiting theory...

Comment: yeh seriously lads just keep going in and out of convos with the jarl and the dragon will turn around and walk towards the exit, i had the same problem but hey presto

Comment: I had the same prob and I think I figured out what causes it: if you attack odalviing once he's been captured (even a single strike or the most minor destruction spell) this 'bug' seems to occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't wait in the room with Odahviing because of "nearby enemies", so in my attempt to make the Jarl leave, I went to another zone, waited there, and returned. Afterwards, I was able to wait in the room with Odahviing. This also resulted in not everyone immediately attacking him once he was free, which solved my problem.

I think it must have been a glitch that never cleared Odahviing as an enemy when he was captured. If this happens for anyone else, try zoning back and forth to see if it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah leave the big room wait a view secs and come back then do it (MAKE SURE YOU DID THIS AFTER THE WIZARD ANNOYS THE DRAGON) Good luck, im sure this will work if people are still having these problems :)

Answer (score 0):

When you release him ensure your going up the stairs and talking to the guard about releasing him.

Comment: Talked to the guard, and the Jarl launched his attack. Pulled the chain myself, and the Jarl launched his attack. :(

Answer (score 0):

What I did was when I released him I talked to the Jarl so that he wouldn't attack.

Answer (score 0):

Walk out the room and go back in, that worked for me!